# Reading .ply files in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, visualization, mesh, matlab-cvst

How do I read a mesh file (.ply) and display it in Matlab?

Also, how can I change the camera viewpoint of said model?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=.ply+matlab

Comment: @HughNolan Yeah, I tried that already but thanks :)

Comment: And the first link has a function for reading .ply files, and the second link has a link to a whole toolbox for manipulating .ply files. What are you missing?

Comment: @HughNolan this is as ridiculous as me asking how do I write a hello world program and you telling me C++ has a whole std lib which you can use. For someone who is new to Matlab, this really doesn't help. I'm aware tools exist, I just have no idea how to use them

Comment: seriously? If you are so new to any language that you can't run a hello world program, asking a question here about how to make one instead of taking some time to acquaint yourself with the language is what I call "ridiculous".

Comment: @HughNolan That was just an example to illustrate my point, I don't bucket rendering a 3D mesh with writing a hello world problem, but clearly to you everything you can do is trivial. What is the point of a Q&A site if you don't get answers. Anyone can google, but may not necessarily know how to interpret the results. Your trolling by pasting a google search query in the comments is ignorant and obnoxious

Comment: Right. You don't, and that's fair enough. But a single function call to a filename, as the answer below demonstrates? I don't see how that is confusing to the point of needing to ask how to run a function (pretty much the most basic thing you do). And that you seem to be pretty proficient in other languages indicates you understand function calls, and file names, and so on. It just seems lazy to have such functions in the first google results, and ignore them without referencing them or your attempts to understand them. Anyway, sorry I'm being a dick.

Comment: @HughNolan I am mainly asking as not sure if there is a standardized way of doing it. For everything 101 people decide to write open source implementations but most of the time they aren't needed or the language has evolved to incorporate this functionality as it is commonly used. As I am very new to Matlab I figured this would be the place that people would tell me. Probably should have included that in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to this link : http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/ply_display/ply_display.m

and save this file.

The `ply_display.m` is a Matlab function (as opposed to a Matlab script). A Matlab function will usually need an input. You can call the `ply_display` function by being in the same folder as the `.m` file. You call it this way :

```
ply_display('file.ply')
%where
%'file.ply' is the name of the file
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I change the viewing angles to a set camera coordinate?

Comment: @Aly You can use the [view](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) function. Place it after the line #53 in the `ply_display.m` file.

Answer (score 3):

I see that this question was raised 2 years ago. But MATLAB R2015a seems to have what you wanted:

ptCloud = pcread(filename)

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcread.html

Comment: Note that pcread doesn't handle range_grids. Still looking for something that does